# How can python's str.maketrans() function be made non-case sensitive?

Tags: python

```
 def rot13(message):
    #your code here
    dict = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm')
    res = message.lower().translate(dict)
    return res
```

The above code is meant to convert a regular input string into ROT13 case. (a code where the letter of the alphabet is increased by 13 places). The code works, however, it doesn't keep the original cases of the string, that is, it returns the string in lower case. How can i change this code to make in non-case sensitive?

Comment: Just add the uppercase letters you want to translate

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks man, i can't believe i never thought about that, sheesh.

Comment: And, remove `.lower()` from `res = message.lower().translate(dict)`